# c++ dynamic allocated variables , what is the flow of execution?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic

I have few questions:

**1)** why when I created more than two dynamic allocated variables the difference between their memory address is 16 bytes. (I thought one of the advantages of using dynamic variables is saving memory, so when you delete unused variable it will free that memory); but if the difference between two dynamic variables is 16 bytes even using a short integer, then there a lot of memery that I will not benifit .

**2)** creating a dynamic allocated variable using new operator.

```
int x;
cin >> x;
int* a = new int(3);
int y = 4;
int z = 1;
```

In the e.g above. what is the flow of execution of this program. is it gonna store all  variable likes x,a,y and z in the stack and then will store the value 3 in the address that a points to?

**3)** creating a dynamic alloated array.

```
int x;
cin >> x;
int* array = new int[x];
int y = 4;
int z = 1;
```

and the same question here.

**4)** does the size of the heap(free scope) depend on how much of memory im using in the code area,the stack are, and the global area ?

Comment: *"I have **two** questions"* -- "**1)**", "**2)**", "**3)**", "**4)**" :)

Comment: *"I thought one of the advantages of using dynamic variables is saving memory"* well, definitely not when used for small single objects.

Comment: does the compiler ignore setting anything that is dynamic allocated and let the runtime system to store that variable in the heap. so if it need the length of an array like in e.g 3). it will find it in the stack ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Storing small values like integers on the heap is fairly pointless because you use the same or more memory to store the pointer. The 16 byte alignment is just so the CPU can access the memory as efficiently as possible.
2. Yes, although the stack variables might be allocated to registers; that is up to the compiler.
3. Same as 2.
4. The size of the heap is controlled by the operating system and expanded as necessary as you allocate more memory.

Comment: 1- what do you mean by :"so the cpu can access the memory as efficiently as possible" ? why it does not depend on the type of the value like in the stack .
2-we know that dynamic variable will existe in the runtime, in that time z and y will already stored. 3 will be the last thing that will be stored 
3-if the order is how it look, why not using normal variable instead of dynamic?
4-If I used a lot of variables on the stack and I have a small memory, could that make the heap have no memory because it all taked by the heap ?

Comment: 1: CPUs can only access memory quickly when they are aligned properly. Unaligned accesses require reading more than is necessary then extracting the appropriate bits, which is obviously slower. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) for more detail. 2: 3 is stored on the heap when it is allocated, before `y` and `z`. 3: I don't know. You're not doing anything with your array.. 4: I don't understand what you mean by this. Regardless, the size of the stack is static; if you put too much on it you will get a stack overflow and crash your program.

Comment: @AbdessamadBond Because the allocator calls some low-level memory allocation function that doesn't know (and doesn't want to know) anything about types. Where do you even specify a type in the not-so-low-level `malloc` function (or the C++ equivalent `operator new`, which likely just calls `malloc` itself)? So these allocation functions need to provide alignment suited to any expected type (usually 8 or 16 bytes).

Comment: Actually, 3 does need to be dynamic because you don't know the size of the array at compile time. Variable sized arrays must be stored on the heap (barring [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which aren't supported in C++, though they are in C99).

Comment: @spencercw: regarding the static size of the stack... this is actually an implementation detail. Modern languages have variably-sized stacks and gcc has introduced an option to have this available in C++.

Comment: @spencercw does the compiler ignore setting anything that is dynamic allocated and let the runtime system to store that variable in the heap. so if it need the length of an array like in e.g 3). it will find it in the stack ?

Comment: @AbdessamadBond Stack values are assigned at runtime as well. For example your `y` assignment might generate something like this: `mov         [y],4` (i.e., move 4 into the location of `y`).

Comment: @spencercw if the stack values are also assigned at runtime why when you create an array with unknown lendth we use dynamic allocated ?

Comment: For stack variables the values themselves are set at runtime, but the amount of space they take must be known at compile time so the compiler can allocate the right amount of space. For this reason, variable sized arrays must be allocated on the heap; the size of the pointer to the array is always the same, so that can go on the stack, but the size of the array itself could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the examples, `a` and `array` are both "stack" variables. The data they point to is not.

I put stack in quotes because we are not going to concern ourselves with hardware detail here, but just the semantics. They have the semantics of stack variables.

Comment: They may be register-only and not stack allocated, though. Other variables may not exist at all because of dead code elimination.

Comment: by "stack" read "automatic". You do not have to worry about how they are really implemented in the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The chunks of heap memory which you allocate need to store some housekeeping data so that the allocator (the code which works in behind of `new`) could work. The data usually includes chunk length and the address of next allocated chunk, among other things — depending on the actual allocator.

In your case, the service data are stored directly in front of (and, maybe, behind of, too) the actual allocated chunk. This (plus, likely, alignment) is the reason of 16 byte gap you observe.

Comment: @VladLazarenko well, I'm from Kiev, so we could probably meet. But I don't recognize you :)

Comment: We don't know each other, I just used to have a similar nickname. I am from New York.. but once upon a time I used to live in Kiev, too :)